# Terraform nested resource creation

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I required to create resources in nested way, in my case I am creating Azure management groups hierarchy,

Below is modules/mg code

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_management_group" "mgmt" {
  count = length(var.management_structure)
  display_name = var.management_structure[count.index]["name"]
  parent_management_group_id = var.parent_id
  subscription_ids = var.management_structure[count.index]["subs"]
  
}
```

Variables.tf

```
variable "parent_id" {
    type = string
    default = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xxxxxx-x--x--x-xxxxx"
}

variable "management_structure" {
    default = [
        {
            name = "App"
            subs = []
            childs = [
                {
                    name = "Prod"
                    subs = []
                },
                {
                    name = "Test"
                    subs = []
                },
                {
                    name = "Dev"
                    subs = []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name = "Platform"
            subs = []
            childs = [
                {
                    name = "security"
                    subs = []
                },
                {
                    name = "network"
                    subs = []
                },
                {
                    name = "storage"
                    subs = []
                    childs = [
                        {
                            name = "Prod"
                            subs = []
                        },
                        {
                            name = "Test"
                            subs = []
                        },
                        {
                            name = "Dev"
                            subs = []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  
}
```

I am calling from root main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.56.0"
    }   
}
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  
}

module "create_mg" {
    source = "./modules/mg"
  
}
```

Above code works and it only creates two Management group one is "App" and another is "platform"

My modules/main.tf required to be modified in order to support nested loop and pass parent IDs respectively example App resource ID should pass to child resource Prod, Test, Dev

any help here will be greatly appreciated and I am okay to change input format if required

Comment: If you check [TF docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/management_group) you will see that `child` block does not exist. Its not clear then, what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Marcin, I required to create managent groups as per management_structure variable

Comment: @Marcin, Also removed dynamic block to avoid confusion, my understanding  dynamic blocks was different

Comment: But using `dynamic` blocks you can achieve the nested loop configuration for management groups. @sagar

Comment: @Jahnavi as per Marcin dynamic blocks does not support

Comment: You can specify the child resource within the parent or outside the parent too. Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/child-resource-name-type.md). Is this works for you? @sagar